# Using CSS to display data as a list?

Tags: css, reactjs, contentful

This is how my data gets rendered:

[image]

You can see above that it renders the data input next to each other. Can I use CSS to display the text as a list?

My contentful query:

```
query MyQuery {
  allContentful {
    edges {
      node {
        feelings
      }
    }
  }
}

OUTPUT:

{
  "data": {
    "allContentful": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "feelings": [
              "Happy / Good Mood",
              "Creative",
              "Sleepy / Couch Lock"
            ]
          }
        },

And here is the return:

const StrainTemplate = ({
    data: {
        strain: {
            feelings,
        },
    },

<p className="info-text"{feelings}</p>
```

Comment: how to you render the text into ```info-text```? Can you post the code?

Comment: I normally query a list of inputs from contentful, so It would look like <p>{feelings}</p> inside of {feelings} 3 data inputs getting rendered

Comment: ```{feelings}``` is those 3 words separately(eg. separate by whitespace/comma...)? If so, I may have a way to do that

Answer (score 2):

If it's rendered like in your images, then you can use `white-space: pre;` to include the `whitespace`

```css
.info-text {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p class='info-text'>
  Happy / Good Mood
  Creative
  Sleepy / Couchy Look
</p>
```

**Note**: this will work if your rendered content has a whitespace and will follow it like `[Tab Space]` or `[New Line]`, but if your rendered content only contains `[Space]` then it will remain in the same line

Comment: Thank you. That would be a solution. Is there no way to make each appear below each other?

Comment: @patrick then you should change the markup of how you render it, maybe change your way from `<p>{feelings}</p>` to `{list-feelings}` and change the content for each inputs to include the `HTML Markup` either `p` or `div`?

Comment: @patrick maybe you can add the `contentful` code that you use to render `.info-text` part

Comment: I've edited my question above. There you can see how I query ```{feelings}```

Comment: @patrick Sorry I have never used `contentful` before, but from the tutorials online, I think it has to do something with how you render the `renderNode` part with your `<p className="info-text">{feelings}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

Not a CSS solution but can you directly make it as the `li` elements

```
feeling.map(eachWord => <li>{eachWord}</li>)
```